# I can't delete an application from my profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, se-applications

On this website, when I go to my *Settings*, then *Applications*, and I click on *Remove*, the view is scrolled to the top but nothing else happen. I don't see any web request in the network tab of my browser.

Here it is:

> [image: "Applications" page in settings with faulty "Remove" button circled]

I use Firefox 92.0 on Linux.

Comment: Solution: don't remove it. :-D